# Declare a subclass method as a friend of the base class

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to C++ and OOP and was given a problem that I struggled with. I was asked to design classes to represent employees and managers. My implementation is below.

```
class Manager;

class Employee {
  private:
    int salary;
  public:
    std::string name;
    Manager* manager;
    Employee(int salary, std::string name, Manager* manager) : salary(salary), name(name), manager(manager) {}
    int getSalary() {
      return this->salary;
    }
    friend int Manager::giveRaise(Employee, int); // incomplete type manager named in nested name specifier
};

class Manager : Employee {
  private:
    std::string perks;
    std::vector<Employee> employees;
  public:
    Manager(std::string perks, int salary, std::string name, Manager* manager) : Employee(salary, name, manager) {
      this->perks = perks;
    }
    int getEmployeeSalary(Employee e) {
      if (e.manager == this) {
        return e.getSalary();
      }
      throw new std::invalid_argument("Employee is not managed by this manager");
    }
    int giveRaise(Employee e, int new_salary) {
      if (e.manager == this) {
        e.salary = new_salary; // Can't access private method
      }
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, I can't declare the giveRaise method as a friend because I haven't defined the manager class at that point. However, I'm not sure how to rearrange the code to get around this error. I don't want to make the salary field protected because I only want a specific manager to be able to access it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your efforts must be shown in public (e.g. your code).

Comment: Serious misunderstanding of the purpose of public and private by whoever set this assignment.

Comment: `manager_bonus = 10 * sum(employee_bonuses)`. That's all you need to know.

Comment: I will add the code in a moment. @john The private and public fields were how I chose to implement it. The assignment just said other employees should not have access to each other's salaries and IDs (except for their manager). I wasn't sure how else to implement it.

Comment: Well, do you know inheritance? I suggest, you create an abstract class `Person`, and inherit classes `Manager` and `Employee`.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31: With multiple levels of management being common, `Manager` should probably inherit from `Employee`. I don't know if a `Person` abstract class is helpful or not.

Comment: @FredLarson, And make `managers access to a private field of only a subset of the employee class` protected? Excellent idea. Thanks :)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Thank you for your suggestion! I'm not sure how adding an abstract class solves criteria 4 however. I'm envisioning a scheme where each person has a salary that is private. How would a manager be able to access a person's salary in that case?

Comment: Yes. I was wrong. Follow @FredLarson's suggestion :)

Comment: The only ways to be able to read the `private` data of another class are A) an accessible getter function and B) `friend`ship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a getter method for that field in the employee class that checks if the caller is the manager. If so, return the value.